# Java copiar ArrayList tipo INTEGER a array tipo INT

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Necesito manejar arrays dinamicos por lo que emplee un arraylist, considerando que no hay arraylist tipo int use un tipo integer, pero en la funcion que necesito usar los valores del arraylist, solo acepta tipo INT, por lo que necesito copiarlos a un array de tipo INT, actualmente intento hacerlo asi:

```
ArrayList<Integer> NewptsX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> NewptsY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int[] ptsX = NewptsX.toArray();
int[] ptsY = NewptsY.toArray();
```

Funcion que requeire valores INT:

```
h.drawPolygon(ptsX, ptsY, NLados);
h.fillPolygon(ptsX, ptsY, NLados);
```

Comment: Bienvenido alguna razón en especial porque no usar los array Integer?

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar explicar que Integer es un objeto (y por tanto puede ser nulo) y que int es un tipo de datos primitivo.
Hay una manera genérica de hacer esto, y es utilizando la propiedad existente desde java 1.5 que se denomina unboxing, por la cual el compilador hace una conversión automática de Integer a int. Solo hay que aplicarla para cada uno de los elementos del array de Integer:

```
int i=0;
for (int valor : NewptsX) {
    ptsX[i++] = valor;
}
```

Si queremos evitar posibles NullPointerException (ya que Integer puede ser nulo), tenemos el siguiente código:

```
int i=0;
for (Integer valor : NewptsX) {
    ptsX[i++] = (valor != null ? valor : 0);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ya que el `Integer` y el `int` son diferentes aunque aceptan el mismo dato debes de hacerlos de la siguiente manera:

Utilizando Java 8

Con Java 8, `int[]` se puede convertir a `Integer:

```
Integer[] primerInteger = Arrays.stream( ptsX ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
Integer[] segundoInteger = IntStream.of( ptsY ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
```

La otra manera seria usando un cliclo for

```
Integer[] nuevoArray = new Integer[ptsX.length];
int i = 0;
for (int valor : ptsX) {
    nuevoArray[i++] = Integer.valueOf(valor);
}
```